# Does ganache-cli support istanbul hardfork?

Tags: ganache, istanbul

I am trying to run `ganache-cli` with istanbul --hardfork, but I am having following error:

`Error: Hardfork istanbul not set as supported in supportedHardforks`

---

```
$ ganache-cli --version
Ganache CLI v6.4.1 (ganache-core: 2.5.3)

$ ganache-cli --allowUnlimitedContractSize --port 8547 --gasLimit 6721975 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul
Error: Hardfork istanbul not set as supported in supportedHardforks
    at e.setHardfork (/Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:2:148221)
    at new e (/Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:2:147540)
    at new _ (/Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:490034)
    at v.createVMFromStateTrie (/Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:47:116822)
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:47:116382
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:47:117447
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:1841439
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:1840514
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:1845356
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:1842719
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:1863594
    at /Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:1870971
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/alper/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:61:1869433)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:242:13)
```

**[Q]** What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of December 30, 2019, `ganache-cli` support for Istanbul is only available via [version 6.8.0-istanbul0](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/releases/tag/v6.8.0-istanbul.0) which is marked as a beta.

To upgrade to this version:

```
npm uninstall ganache-cli -g
npm install ganache-cli@istanbul -g
```

Comment: So how bad is it if I have conducted all of my "localhost tests" on ganache-cli v6.7.0? Is there anything that I should worry about?

Comment: The biggest concern is around the `SLOAD` gas reprice and it's potential impact on `address.transfer`. See https://medium.com/consensys-diligence/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now-b1b6d2d00faf

Comment: Also, if you are using solc 0.6.0 you should compile with the `--evm-version petersburg` flag when doing local testing, to avoid use of the new `SELFBALANCE` opcode.  But that's not a security issue - just a potential source of confusion when tests fail :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm aware of that one... though I believe it's actually from v0.5.13. See my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78598/16043) from yesterday (feel free to correct it if I was wrong in assuming that).

Comment: Oooh good catch! It says `istanbul` has been the default evm ruleset since `0.5.14` but it must have been available prior if `SELFBALANCE` was in use in `0.5.13`.

Comment: For Istanbul, for now, best `sol`c version to use is 0.5.15 or 0.6.0?